# Как правильно встроить google map в качестве фона

Tags: google-maps

хочу сделать  фон для блока

```
<div class="block">

  <div class="container">
  //content
  </div>
</div>
```

тег `<div class="block">` будет отображать фон, но при этом должен быть под контентом

заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так, но карта будет некликабельная, если нужно чтобы работала, тогда нужно еще

```
.container {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 250px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d577325.3484153093!2d36.82509701532533!3d55.58152434359989!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x46b54afc73d4b0c9%3A0x3d44d6cc5757cf4c!2z0JzQvtGB0LrQstCw!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1554563819157!5m2!1sru!2sru"
      width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    Контент
  </div>
</div>
```